# HTTP PUT / PATCH / POST - is there any technical difference except REST semantics?

Tags: http, browser, server

I am interested whether there's some actual browser / server behaviour, which is different for a different verb. I am not interested in a RFC specification or REST conventions here.

You can't send a request body with GET, but are there some technical differences between PUT/PATCH/POST?

Comment: The RFCs lists the behavioral differences, so it's a bit weird to ask for differences but exclude the specification.

Comment: I am asking about the differences in external behaviour - deserialization / caching, itd. Something that does not depend on internal API code and its compliance to the specification.

Comment: You're asking about these in general, so any general behavior that's different between the methods is in specifications, including how browsers should behave, caching, etc. Anything that's not general, but specific to an application is hard to enumerate.

Answer (score 1):

Let's first do a few officials then try to answer your question.

Although you are saying not being interested, when a product implements these keywords they do follow the guideline of these documents as they themselves obey describe what is REQUIRED, what are PROHIBITED, and what are (NOT) RECOMMENDED.

you will see this paragraph in all of them.

```
  The key words "MUST", "MUST NOT", "REQUIRED", "SHALL", "SHALL
  NOT", "SHOULD", "SHOULD NOT", "RECOMMENDED",  "MAY", and
  "OPTIONAL" in this document are to be interpreted as described in
  [RFC 2119](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2119).
```

And for clarity, POST and PUT were introduced together in 1996, and PATCH was added later in 2010 from necessity.

POST is the base one to be used in any transaction. You can forget the others. You don't have to use PUT, PATCH, even DELETE, or other verbs. Put a field in your data for the method you want to process, and process the data according to its value. The only thing you need is to make sure to check that method field.

PUT will ease the updating of documents a bit easier. But if you use PUT, you will now be depending on the library you use to discriminate the requests, and make a route matching the PUT. You also need to use PUT on the client-side, and if you want a lightweight library for that (for example on an IoT device) you may not have it available, then your backend will be useless for this use case or you will need to upgrade to a more sophisticated client device.

Other than being lightweight on requests, PATCH is the most dangerous amongst them. As said, it was added for the necessity of updating documents only partially. PATCH'ing is less expensive in terms of data size, but if many requests try to patch the same document at the same time (or in very close intervals) clients will not get the responses they would expect. Thus when implementing a backend, one must be extra cautious of the request collisions.

RFC has this in the document and warns beforehand.

```
PATCH is neither safe nor idempotent
```

Now we are a little bit more acknowledged, let me go about "whether there's some actual browser / server behaviour".

If they follow the REQUIREMENTS and PROHIBITIONS, then they all have the core functionality. you can expect the same response for the same request from all of them unless you use some extras that are implemented by RECOMMENDATIONS. They may choose not to implement, however. I may refuse to use anything other than GET and POST in my own server. Or some libraries may not have anything other than these two in their browser. Yet if we have them they should behave the same to carry data.